# what is the difference in .SetInputConnection() and .SetInput()

Tags: python, vtk

I was learning vtk on http://www.uppmax.uu.se/docs/w/index.php/How_to_Read_vtk_Files
with this example.

I found there is no difference when using

```
arrowGlyph.SetInput(reader.GetOutput())
```

or

```
arrowGlyph.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
```

I know that Getoutput() gives you a vtkPolyData and GetOutputPort() gives you a vtkAlgorithmOuPut. But I don't know what is going on under the hood. Can they be used interchangeably?

(my vtk version is 5.4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the VTK [wiki](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/PipelineInput), the former is deprecated in favor of using the latter new pipeline API. How I understand it is with `SetInputConnection`, you don't care whether it is the actual data or the output of some long chain of filters.

So I think in version 5 they might be used interchangeably but the first is being phased out starting in version 6. You can find Python examples [like this](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/Visualization/SphereTexture) on the wiki where you can only use `SetInputConnection` in version 6.